# How do I cimport scipy.spatial.ckdtree?

Tags: python, scipy, cython

I am rewriting some of my code using Cython, and want to type a `ckdtree` variable. I am currently doing

```
cimport scipy.spatial.ckdtree as ckdtree

cdef tuple remove_labels(double[:, :] x_train, double[:, :] y_train):
    cdef ckdtree.KDTree tree

    // ...
    tree = ckdtree.KDTree(x_rest_view)
```

but I get several errors:

When importing, I get the error

```
'scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pxd' not found
```

In line

```
cdef ckdtree.KDTree tree
```

I get

```
'KDTree' is not a type identifier
```

In line

```
tree = ckdtree.KDTree(x_rest_view)
```

I get

```
cimported module has no attribute 'KDTree'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It possible (likely?) that this subpackage is a mix of python and compiled code.  Have you examined the github source?  Not everything can be `cimported` - admittedly it's been some since I experimented with cython.  The code in the previous cython suggestion was for an iteration heavy function using basic calculations, not something depending on a scipy module.

Comment: It appears that there is a Cython version (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/spatial/_ckdtree.pyx), but there isn't a pxd file for Cython to import. Can you import a pyx directly?